# When I load a page in an iframe, the char-set won't work

Tags: html, iframe, character-encoding

So I'm showing a receipt which contains special characters. Before opening a new tab, I show a preview of the page in an iframe. With the exact same url, the iframe one replaces the special characters by black diamonded ?. I read the iframe's charset-encoding should be totally independant from the parent frame. Can somebody explain me this?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page inside the iframe, it should have a own declared charset, nested on a head tag, like this example:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<head>
```

Besides, you can declare a charset via HTTP header: http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset